# How do i know if i have to request with PostgreSQL/MySQL/Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I use the tool "dbeaver" to request on a Redshift server.
I don't understand what language i have to use.

Some functions like "LAST_DAY" doesn't exist so i thought i have to use PostgreSQL, who doesn't work either.

Can Dbeaver give me the correct information ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Redshift uses SQL - as all relational databases do. The list of functions is [documented in the manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_SQLCommandRef.html)

Comment: Yes, but there is SQL function who does not work in Redshift

Comment: @SRP the documented functions will work. Of course, not all of the functions implemented e.g. in Postgres are supported in Redshift.

Comment: In dbeaver, the best driver to use is the Redshift one, but Postgres may work as well. That doesn't however have any effect on the supported functions, since the server interprets the SQL statements.

Comment: LAST_DAY is in redshift.  Right here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LAST_DAY.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to choose the Driver that matches the database so that they can properly communicate. Sometimes, an alternate driver is acceptable because Amazon Redshift was originally based on PostgreSQL.

The driver is merely the means of communication with the database. It does not impact which commands can be used. All commands are sent to, and executed on, the database server.

The `LAST_DAY` function is available in Amazon Redshift. See: [LAST_DAY function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LAST_DAY.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My main problem was alternate driver worked sometimes. I fixed it after your comments, now it's ok i can use the last_day function